# using Fiddler to replace HREF

Tags: http, href, code-injection, fiddler

I want to replace the HREF values of a website to my local server hosted images using Fiddler. Can this be done and how?

Answer (score 1):

Open fiddler and switch to the AutoResponder tab. Do a hard-refresh on your site, and let all of the session files load up in the left panel. Once you see your page containing your links, make sure it's decoded (right click and hit 'decode').

Drag your file over into the AutoResponder panel (you may need to enable AutoResponders, make sure you let unmatched sessions pass-thru). Once in the AutoResponder tab, right-click your page and click "edit response." From here, you can modify the contents of this page.

From here on out, refreshing your site will load that file from the AutoResponder instead of from the server or cache.